# Simple JSP-Spring 3 dropdown list not working

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I know this should be pretty easy but I'm stuck after trying several things.
I'm only trying to display in my jsp a basic dropdown list. Spring version is 3 so I want everything to work with annotations.

JSP form with dropdown list:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="countryForm">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Country :</td>
                            <td><form:select path="country">
                                    <form:option value="Select" label="Select" />
                                </form:select>
                            </td>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
```

CountryForm.java is a plain object with a single String attribute "country", with its getters and setters.

Controller who deals with the GET request is the following:

```
@Controller
public class CountryFormController {

@RequestMapping(value = "MainView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {
        CountryForm cform = new CountryForm();
        model.put("countryForm", cform);
        return "MainView";
    }
}
```

However, when I redirect to the JSP "MainView" I get the typical error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'countryForm' available as request attribute
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:424)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `select` tag in the Spring TagLib needs to be provided with a collection, map or array of options.  I'm not sure what you would like these to be so I will make some assumptions.

You need to include a collection, map or array of objects in your controller.  Ideally you would have a `Country` class and create new instances for a set of countries.  For the example to work with your code, I just created a static list of countries.  Add the list to your model and then modify the `select` tag, setting the `options` to `${countries}`.  Assuming `country` is a field of type `String` on `CountryForm` with appropriate get/set methods, the country should data-bind to field when the form is submitted.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class CountryFormController {

@RequestMapping(value = "MainView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model) {

        List<CountryForm> cfs = new ArrayList<CountryForm>();
        cfs.add("United States");
        cfs.add("Canada");
        model.put("countries", cfs);
        model.put("countryForm", cform);
        return "MainView";
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<form:select path="countryForm.country" options="${countries}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it but keeps throwing the same error, pointing to "countryForm" (still seems to not being binded)...

Comment: @Hauri Do you have getter/setter methods for the field on countryForm?

Comment: Yes, I have them, of course. I know this should be simple, but I've tried several options and always got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have sample code at [GitHub](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke), try it an let me know. Look at [landing.jsp](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/landing.jsp) and [UserController](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke/blob/master/src/com/example/UserController.java)

```
<form:select path="users[${status.index}].type" >
  <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
  <form:options itemValue="name" itemLabel="description" />
</form:select>
```

HTH